# How to add fixtures for Strapi unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, fixtures, strapi

How can I add fixtures for testing Strapi project with jest.

and is there a way to add such testing data in Strapi, like fixtures in ruby on rails?

this is an example of rubyOnRail fixtures:

```yaml
# lo & behold!  I am a YAML comment!
david:
 name: David Heinemeier Hansson
 birthday: 1979-10-15
 profession: Systems development
 
steve:
 name: Steve Ross Kellock
 birthday: 1974-09-27
 profession: guy with keyboard
```

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: There appear to be at least two plug-ins for Strapi 3: [strapi-plugin-import-export-content](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-import-export-content) and [strapi-plugin-seeds](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-seeds) but neither have been updated for Strapi 4.

Answer (score 0):

[strapi-plugin-import-export-content](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-import-export-entries) has been updated for `Strapi4` but requires some work to inject exported data to its apis (Authentication mainly). Also, single types have no export/import buttons by default so I don't know if the `import/export` apis work with them.

For now, the easiest workaround I found is to set a dedicated `sqlite` db for tests with seed data.

`!!! Beware of the credentials of your super admin account if you do that, DO NOT PUSH TRUE CREDENTIALS ONLINE, they could remain in old commits for ever !!!`

Here are some scripts I use to export/import fixtures:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# tests/export_sqlite_fixtures.sh
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )

sqlite3 "$SCRIPT_DIR/../.tmp/data.db" ".output $SCRIPT_DIR/fixtures.sql.dump" ".dump"
```

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# tests/import_sqlite_fixtures.sh
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )

sqlite3 "$SCRIPT_DIR/../.tmp/data.db" ".output $SCRIPT_DIR/fixtures.sql.dump" ".dump"
```

Then in my CI pipe i just add (Github action here):

```
    - name: Populate sqlite db with fixtures
      run: ./tests/import_sqlite_fixtures.sh

    - name: build Strapi
      run: yarn build

    ...
```

NB: The extension of the export is `.sql.dump` to keep the `*.sql` rule in the `.gitignore`